# Извлечение уникальных значений из ячеек массива. Вывод цветов товара

Tags: php, sql

Есть [таблица](https://yadi.sk/i/hTvxtklNmM6ZU)

Таблица осуществляет связку с таблицей товаров. Остановился на такой таблице параметров. Возможно она некорректна или с ней будет неудобно работать в дальнейшем - хотел и об этом узнать мнение опытных людей.
Суть в том, что выводить параметры хочу, начиная с цвета. Нужно выбрать все встречающиеся идентификаторы цвета из колонки `color_id` для определённого товара `item_id`. То есть может быть несколько совпадающих идентификаторов цвета для определённого товара, а нужно выбрать по одному. Например, в вышеуказанной таблице все значения `color_id` - 1,1,2,3 - нужно вывести 1,2,3. Если будет 1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5 - вывести 1,2,3,4,5. Вероятно есть схема работы с выборкой цвета более удобная, но пока не додумал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам придется сделать подзапрос, чтоб выделить сначала уникальные элементы, а уже потом сгруппировать

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (id int, item int, color int);
insert into t values
(1,1,1),
(2,1,1),
(3,1,2),
(4,1,3);

select item, group_concat(color) from (select distinct item, color from t) t1 group by item
```

результат

```
item    group_concat(color)
1       1,2,3
```

Comment: а с помощью функции `array_unique()` никак не выкрутиться?

Comment: если в коде уже потом, то  никаких проблем - array_unique() и implode(). Только правильнее от мускула получить правильные данные, мне кажется :)

Comment: В комментариях к [спецификации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php) функции `array_unique()` нашёл такую функцию: `function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) {
    $temp_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    $key_array = array();
   
    foreach($array as $val) {
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) {
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
            $temp_array[$i] = $val;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $temp_array;
} ` Работает